# bellman ford and one surprizing fact

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, shortest-path, discrete-mathematics

I ran into a very surprising local contest problem.

> after finishing bellman ford algorithm, if we continue to updating
> distance and distance of one vertex **v** being updated, then **v** is
> on negative cycle.

there is very easily counterexample that the above sentence is false, but two times asking from my instructor, he told me this is true. what is the trick here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @nirshahar please be careful. fact is about vertex V that be on negative cycle, not about existing a negative cycle.

Comment: Please see my picture. please relax vt- vu, uv, su -- after three steps the following figure shown distances. bellman ford check negative cycle d[v]+0<d[t] so t not belong to negative cycle but this equality hold and we can update it. there is no necessary condition here (I think) @nirshahar

Comment: would you please consider my example and a bit more detail as an answer @nirshahar

Comment: Looking again at this, I think you are right. The (correct) statement probably is "if $v$ is on a negative cycle, then there is some $u$ on this cycle that is updated in the last (extra) bellman-ford iteration"

Comment: Or maybe "if $v$ is updated in the extra bellman-ford iteration, then there is some negative cycle $C$ that $t$ is reachable from".

Comment: It might help to know [which edition of which *Text Book*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) the raster image is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this statement is not correct.  Since, especially, $t$ will potentially be updated after $n$ iterations.

A correct statement is that if a vertex $v$ gets updated after the $n$ first rounds, then there is a path from $s$ to a negative cycle $C$ that ends in $v$.

To *find* a negative cycle, you start from $v$ (the vertex that gets updated in the $n+1$st round) and go backwards (in the dp table) until you reach a vertex $u$ twice.  The path between the two occurrences of $u$ is a constitutes a negative cycle.

---

In your example, if $t$ gets updated, then you follow backwards $t \leftarrow v \leftarrow u \leftarrow v$, and the negative cycle is $C = \langle v, u, v\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarification. would you please my new figure attached. what does mean $pi$ values shown vertexes lie on negative cycle?