# If the distance to a vertex is updated in the n-th relaxation of Bellman Ford, is that vertex on a negative-weight cycle?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, trees, shortest-path

Recently I asked a question [Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148522/bellman-ford-and-one-surprizing-fact) about following topics:

> after finishing bellman ford algorithm, if BF continue to update
> distances and distance value related to one vertex v being
> updated,then v is on negative cycle. [***]

from my counterexample I think this is a wrong sentence.

I see in the implementation of the following problem [Here](https://reasonabledeviations.com/2019/04/21/currency-arbitrage-graphs-2/) That mentioned:

> The key idea is that if after n−1 relaxations, there is an edge that
> can be relaxed further then that edge must be on a negative weight
> cycle.

Author says "that edge must be on a negative weight cycle".

I see also in [Here](https://codersatellite.com/question-with-identifier-50886584) that mentioned:

> That is, some nodes not on the negative cycle now have a distance of
> negative infinity from the source because of one or more nodes on the
> path from the source to the node that lie in a negative cycle.

and lastly I read in comments here [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720689/finding-all-vertices-on-negative-cycles) that one user write:

> All vertices that have their distances updated in the n-th phase must
> be on a negative weight cycle, no?

My challenge is via different statements, [***] is a correct or not correct sentence?

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not correct. You can use [your counter-example from before](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148522/bellman-ford-and-one-surprizing-fact), and add redundant nodes to it.

Since the bellman-ford algorithm runs iterations equal to the number of nodes in the graph - you will see that nodes that are reachable from a negative cycle (but not on the negative cycle) will *also* get updated.

---

### The correct statement

To clear things up, here is the correct statement:

**Theorem:**

If a vertex $v$ is updated in the extra iteration of the Bellman-Ford algorithm, then there exists a negative cycle $C$, such that $v$ can be reached from $C$ (i.e, there is a path from any node in $C$ to $v$).

**Proof:**

It is well-known that a graph $G$ contains a negative cycle $\iff$ there exists some vertex that is updated in the extra Bellman-Ford iteration.

Let $v$ be the updated node. Then, consider the sub-graph $G'$ of $G$, consisting only of the nodes that can reach $v$.

Let $d^G_{i}[u]$ be the value given to $u\in G$ in the $i$'th iteration of the bellman ford algorithm on $G$, and equivalently $d^{G'}_{i}[u]$ on $G'$. Its not hard to see that for any $u\in G'$, $d^{G'}_i[u]=d^{G}_i[u]$ (i.e, the bellman-ford on $G$ and $G'$ is equivalent).

Therefore, $v$ must also be updated in the extra iteration if we run Bellman-Ford on $G'$, and thus $G'$ must contain a cycle $C$. But $G'$ contains only nodes that can reach $v$ - so it must hold that there is a path between $C$ and $v$ as required to show.